# How to shrink a rectangular round cornered UIButton to a circular UIButton?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, uibutton, core-animation

With the help of this i was able to shrink the UIButton but atlast i want the UIButton to get rounded.Please help me to get the desired animation in sign up button. The code snippet is :
Follow the link : https://www.dropbox.com/s/rh4tdub3zabxp2j/shot.gif?dl=0

```
self.buttonShrink = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform"];
self.buttonShrink.duration = .2f;
self.buttonShrink.values = @[[NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DMakeScale(1, 1, 1)],[NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DMakeScale(.9,1,1)],[NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DMakeScale(.8,1,1)],[NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DMakeScale(.7,1,1)],[NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DMakeScale(.6,1,1)],[NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DMakeScale(.5,1,1)],[NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DMakeScale(.4,1,1)],[NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DMakeScale(.3,1,1)]];
self.buttonShrink.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseOut];
self.sampleButton.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0,0);
self.sampleButton.alpha = 1;
[self.sampleButton.layer addAnimation:self.buttonShrink forKey:@"buttonScale"];
[self.sampleButton setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did some tinkering and got pretty decent results.

### EDIT:

I just uploaded a demo project to GitHub called [**MorphingButton**](https://github.com/DuncanMC/MorphingButton) (link) that generates the animation below:

[image]

Here's what I did:

I created a normal iOS 8 button in IB (no outline at all) and connected an outlet and an action to it.

I added height and width constraints.

I added code to set the borderColor, borderWidth, and cornerRadius of the button's layer to give it a rounded corner look. This would take some adjustment to make it look like a real rounded rectangle button.

In the IBAction for the button, switch back and forth between making it round and making it rectangular.

### To make the button round:

- Use a UIView animateWithDuration method call to set the button's
  height constraint to it's width constraint (making it square) and invoke `layoutWithNeeded()`
- Use aCABasicAnimation to animate the button's layer's corner radius to 1/2
  the button width.

### To make the button rectangular:

- Use a UIView animateWithDuration method call to set the button's
  height constraint to it's starting height constraint
- Use aCABasicAnimation to animate the button's layer's corner radius to 10 (which looks pretty good for a rounded rectangle button.)

The IBAction and viewDidLoad code would look like this in Objective-C:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  oldHeight = buttonHeightConstraint.constant;
  buttonIsRound = FALSE;
  [super viewDidLoad];
  animationDuration = 0.5;
}

- (IBAction)handleButton:(id)sender
{
  CGFloat newHeight;
  CGFloat newCornerRadius;
  NSLog(@"Entering %s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
  
  if (buttonIsRound)
  {
    //If the button is currently round,
    //go back to the old height/corner radius
    newHeight = oldHeight;
    newCornerRadius = 10;
  }
  else
  {
    //It isn't round now,
    //so make it's height and width the same
    //and set the corner radius to 1/2 the width
    newHeight = buttonWidthConstraint.constant;
    newCornerRadius = buttonWidthConstraint.constant/2;
  }
  
  [UIView animateWithDuration:  animationDuration
                   animations:^
   {
     buttonHeightConstraint.constant = newHeight;
     [button layoutIfNeeded];
   }];
  CABasicAnimation *cornerAnimation = [[CABasicAnimation alloc] init];
  cornerAnimation.keyPath = @"cornerRadius";
  cornerAnimation.fromValue = @(button.layer.cornerRadius);
  cornerAnimation.toValue = @(newCornerRadius);
  cornerAnimation.duration = animationDuration;
  [button.layer addAnimation: cornerAnimation forKey: @"woof"];
  button.layer.cornerRadius = newCornerRadius;
  buttonIsRound = !buttonIsRound;
}
```

The Swift IBAction code for the button looks like this:

```
@IBAction func handleButton(sender: AnyObject)
{
  if !buttonIsRound
  {
    UIView.animateWithDuration(animationDuration)
      {
        self.buttonHeightConstraint.constant = self.buttonWidthConstraint.constant
        self.button.layoutIfNeeded()
        self.buttonIsRound = true
    }
    let cornerAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "cornerRadius")
    cornerAnimation.fromValue = button.layer.cornerRadius
    cornerAnimation.toValue = self.buttonWidthConstraint.constant / 2.0
    cornerAnimation.duration = animationDuration
    button.layer.addAnimation(cornerAnimation, forKey: "woof")
    button.layer.cornerRadius = self.buttonWidthConstraint.constant / 2.0
  }
  else
  {
    UIView.animateWithDuration(animationDuration)
      {
        self.buttonHeightConstraint.constant = self.oldHeight
        self.button.layoutIfNeeded()
        self.buttonIsRound = false
    }
    let cornerAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "cornerRadius")
    cornerAnimation.fromValue = self.buttonWidthConstraint.constant / 2.0
    cornerAnimation.toValue = 10
    cornerAnimation.duration = animationDuration
    button.layer.addAnimation(cornerAnimation, forKey: "woof")
    button.layer.cornerRadius = 10
  }
}
```

Comment: @FionaShoff, is the animation I posted the effect you are after?

Comment: Thanks @duncan. But sorry to say i am new to swift  and really having a very bad idea about it. Could you please help me with objective-c code. And one more thing how to add height and width constraints in code rather than by using storyboard?

Comment: @FionaShoff I'll try to rewrite the code in Objective-C if I get a chance. Why do you need the constraints in code rather than in IB (Interface Builder)? When a view doesn't have a full set of constraints the system adds them, and that could be a problem. Easier to do it in IB

Comment: actually we are in the halfway of our project and i find it hard to integrate IB in the view...

Comment: Setting up constraints in IB is a lot easier than doing it in code.

Comment: @FionaShoff I just posted Objective-C code to do the same animation.

Comment: please if you dont mind ... How to set the width constriants programatically??

Comment: How to create a width constraint, or set the width constraint I already created in my example?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80072/discussion-between-fiona-shoff-and-duncan-c).

Answer (score 0):

I never used this for shrinking but as you are using button layer so why can not you use it cornerRadius. I'm not sure suggestion is ok or not??

Comment: nope bro... suppose a rectangular UIButton on clicking it shrinks with animation and becomes a round button. The above code shrinks the button width wise

Comment: ok then give some minutes I'm going to use it then text you back.. :)

Comment: sorry, still textless but trying too.. as I get success  text you..  :(

Comment: see this video for autolayout constraints -- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rIC8sc7bj20  play after 7 mins and the another way use a frame animation by using image View